# Oracle SQL Developer -- Procedure Declarations/Bodies -- How Do I Separate Them?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, declaration, procedure

Thanks for your help in advance. I'm new to Oracle SQL Developer, and my SQL code works fine, BUT the way it's separated by SQL Developer, makes it not work. I need to have it run in segments like this example:

How I need the code separated (good):
[image: good]
How my code is separated (not good):
[image: not good]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: I have to put a semicolon at the end.

;

Lmao. How silly. Please keep this thread for anyone else who makes a simple mistake.

Regards,